# DateFormat Flutter I am fetching date form json api "2020-04-18T00:00:00" in this format but i want in this format "dd-mm-yyyy"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am fetching Date From json api which is in this format **2020-04-18T00:00:00** but i want date in this format **dd-mm-yy**

```
String date=pALResponse.clmmDate;
DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(date);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`intl`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) package ([installer](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl#-installing-tab-)) to format dates in `Flutter`.

See an example code below:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

main() {
  var now = new DateTime.now();
  var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  String formatted = formatter.format(now);
  print(formatted); // something like 2013-04-20
}
```

There are many options for formatting. From the docs:

```
 ICU Name                   Skeleton
 --------                   --------
 DAY                          d
 ABBR_WEEKDAY                 E
 WEEKDAY                      EEEE
 ABBR_STANDALONE_MONTH        LLL
 STANDALONE_MONTH             LLLL
 NUM_MONTH                    M
 NUM_MONTH_DAY                Md
 NUM_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY        MEd
 ABBR_MONTH                   MMM
 ABBR_MONTH_DAY               MMMd
 ABBR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY       MMMEd
 MONTH                        MMMM
 MONTH_DAY                    MMMMd
 MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY            MMMMEEEEd
 ABBR_QUARTER                 QQQ
 QUARTER                      QQQQ
 YEAR                         y
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH               yM
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH_DAY           yMd
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY   yMEd
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH              yMMM
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH_DAY          yMMMd
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY  yMMMEd
 YEAR_MONTH                   yMMMM
 YEAR_MONTH_DAY               yMMMMd
 YEAR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY       yMMMMEEEEd
 YEAR_ABBR_QUARTER            yQQQ
 YEAR_QUARTER                 yQQQQ
 HOUR24                       H
 HOUR24_MINUTE                Hm
 HOUR24_MINUTE_SECOND         Hms
 HOUR                         j
 HOUR_MINUTE                  jm
 HOUR_MINUTE_SECOND           jms
 HOUR_MINUTE_GENERIC_TZ       jmv
 HOUR_MINUTE_TZ               jmz
 HOUR_GENERIC_TZ              jv
 HOUR_TZ                      jz
 MINUTE                       m
 MINUTE_SECOND                ms
 SECOND                       s
```

See https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html for more info.